# Flutter Error : Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

At first when I installed and ran the Android Studio the app ran perfectly, then after two days for some reason this is happening. Please help me fix this. Thanks

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on GM1910 in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    Not resetting hidden file - C:\Users\zahin\AndroidStudioProjects\project1\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\assets\ss\Thumbs.db

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'.
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\zahin\AndroidStudioProjects\project1\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `flutter clean` or remove the build folder on your project root then try again.